# Disable/enable text field and list box as per value selected in list box

Tags: javascript, html

Disable/enable text field and list box as per user selected value from parent list box.

**Condition:**
if user don't know programming then list box and text box must disable.

However it is not working, I know I am missing something.only Javascript please

```js
function check()
{
//if(document.drop_list.choice[1].checked){
if(document.getElementById("mt").value === 'N'){

document.getElementById("no").disabled=true;
  document.getElementById("txt").disabled=true;
}else{
document.getElementById("no").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("txt").disabled=false;
}
}
```

```html
<form name="drop_list" action="listbox-validation-demock.php" method="post" id='f1'>
Do you want to learn Web programming languages ? 

<select name="Category" id="mt" onChnage="check()">
<option value='Y'>Y</option>
<option value="N">N</option>
</select>

  <br /><br />

<select name="Category" id="no">
<option value=''>Select One</option>
<option value="PHP">PHP</option>
<option value="ASP">ASP</option>
<option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
<option value="HTML with design">HTML</option>
<option value="Perl">Perl</option><option value="MySQL">MySQL</option></select>
  <br /><br />
 Age<input type="text" size="20" id="txt">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should have been :

```
<select name="Category" id="mt" onChange="check()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script works, the only problem is a typo:

```
<select name="Category" id="mt" onChnage="check()"> 
-----------------------------------^^^-------------
```